# Is there any example reference to use KMS keys for encrypting records delivered by firehose in Python 3?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-kms

I am trying to enable encryption of records deliverd to s3 by firehose using KMS key.so that data in s3 will be encrypted. I trying acheive it using cloudformation YAML file and python

I tried using below code under . Is this right way ? we are using lambda to read encrypted files from that bucket than decrypt and send to sftp server.
 ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration:
       BucketARN: !GetAtt s3bucket.Arn
       BufferingHints:
         IntervalInSeconds: '60'
         SizeInMBs: '10'
       CompressionFormat: UNCOMPRESSED
       EncryptionConfiguration:
          KMSEncryptionConfig:
            AWSKMSKeyARN: "arn:aws:kms:...:key/keyvalue'

Is this will be enough or anything else i need to add ? Any better way to acheive this ?